# Converting GeoTIFF to simple XYZ elevation file

Tags: geotiff-tiff, convert, software-recommendations, xyz

Is there a tool to convert a GeoTIFF file to a simple ascii (XYZ) elevation file?

Answer (score 14):

You should be able to do this using the `gdal_translate` command line tool.

http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

To convert to Arc/Info ASCII Grid:

```
gdal_translate -of AAIGrid elevation.tif elevation.asc
```

To convert to ASCII Gridded XYZ:

```
gdal_translate -of XYZ elevation.tif elevation.xyz
```

Binary executables of the GDAL tools are available here: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries

Answer (score 3):

In GRASS GIS, the command [r.out.xyz](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.out.xyz.html) does this conversion job. Instead of first importing the GeoTIFF file, you can simply register it beforehand with [r.external](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.external.html) in the GRASS GIS [location](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Location_and_Mapsets) (i.e. basically the needed project directory).