# GDAL Translate error

Tags: python, gdal, xyz

I am trying to translate a .tif raster to an xyz one in Python

The code is this:

```
import sys
from osgeo import gdal


gdal.AllRegister()
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('Local Disk')

dataset = gdal.Open('C:\Delft3D\Teste\GDAL\clc_raster.tif')

if dataset is None:
    print "Could not!"
    sys.exit(1)

gdal_translate -of XYZ dataset.tif C:\Delft3D\Teste\GDAL\clc_raster.tif.xyz

dataset = None
```

But I get the following error.

```
   gdal_translate -of XYZ dataset.tif C:\Delft3D\Teste\GDAL\clc_raster2.xyz
                        ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know why this error appears. I used the tips from [convert geotiff to simple xyz elevation file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59323/convert-geotiff-to-simple-xyz-elevation-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use another option like:

```
os.system("gdal_translate -of XYZ " + source_file + " " +  out_file)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to execute a command line utility from within Python. To do this you can use `subprocess`, which takes the command line arguments as a list of strings.

```py
import subprocess    
cmd = ["gdal_translate", "-of", "XYZ", "dataset.tif", r"D:\Delft3D\Teste\GDAL\clc_raster.tif.xyz"]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

edit:

Additionally I'd like to point out that a lot of your code is superfluous if you use `subprocess` or `os.system` to execute a command line utility.

This is all you need:

```py
import subrocess

in_file = r"D:\input\dataset.tif"
out_file = r"D:\output\dataset.xyz"

cmd = ["gdal_translate",
       "-of", "XYZ",
       in_file,
       out_file]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Comment: The process runs, but it doesn't create the file. I guess it's something wrong with the command line arguments.

Comment: It should create file at `D:\Delft3D\Teste\GDAL\clc_raster.tif.xyz` as long as you execute the Python script in the same directory as `dataset.tif` and the directory `D:\Delft3D\Teste\GDAL\` already exists.