# Converting coordinate and raster values of each pixel to csv of large raster using Python?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, r, big-data

There should be a simple way to convert a large raster to a csv or dataframe by reading the raster in as chunks, converting raster chunk to table of just three columns (x, y, and values), and outputting to csv or dataframe. I normally use something like the following in R but it only works for rasters much smaller than I'd like and I'd prefer to use python.

```
ras = readGDAL("Agroforestry_crop_setnull.tif")
rasdf= as.data.frame(ras, row.names=NULL, optional=FALSE, xy=FALSE, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I have read about GDALs ReadAsArray and gdal2xyz, I do not know how to use ReadAsArray to get coordinates of pixels in the 3 column table I desire, although it does allow reading the rasters as chunks. gdal2xyz does not provide the raster values of the pixels and does not allow reading as chunks from what I have seen.

In the past I have made use of ArcPy, breaking up the rasters into pieces, converting to points, and adding the coordinates to the attribute fields, then exporting these tables. I am hoping there is a better way, similar to the R solution I posted but for python and big rasters.

Is there a suggestion on reading big rasters as chunks in the csv format I desire -3 columns (X,Y, value)?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the SAGA GIS feature **'Export Grid to XYZ'**. Despite the name this also supports multiband images (e.g. you could export a 'rendered GeoTiff' to get XYZRGBA, as well as getting XYZ from a 1-band DEM). You can also choose whether or not to drop NODATA rows.

I don't have any massive rasters to hand to test this, but you could try that to see if the memory usage and performance is more acceptable than **gdal2xyz**.

Failing that, if you need to write your own code, a python library to look at is [RasterIO](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio). This is a wrapper around GDAL/Numpy and provides a higher level interface. It also allows the [windowed-reading](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/windowed-rw.html) you refer to.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of an option to get a table of just the pixels X/Y coordinates and values? I think I can play around with RasterIO to read the data as chunks but haven't figured out how to get my desired table yet.

Answer (score 3):

Use [gdal_translate](http://gdal.org/gdal_translate.html).  See [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59323/convert-geotiff-to-simple-xyz-elevation-file).  Call gdal_translate as a subprocess from Python.  See my answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42584/how-to-call-gdal-translate-from-python-code) for a how-to on using gdal_translate as a subprocess if you don't already know how.  You can tile your raster if it is huge and perhaps build a VRT.

Alternatively you could see this question on how to [read in chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250197/efficient-way-of-inputting-large-raster-data-into-pytables)s.

Comment: The last link you posted is close to what I am looking for. I need to create a table of just the pixels coordinates and value though instead of the array of the entire raster.